# Custom Vue.js AJAX directives onSuccess processing

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have setup a custom Vue directive for ajax forms, however I would like it to process a custom onSuccess call with the received data...

The directive looks like this:

```
Vue.directive('ajax', {
    bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
        el.addEventListener(
            'submit', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                let formData = new FormData(el);
                let method = el.method.toLowerCase();
                Vue.http[method](el.action, formData).then(response => { // success callback
                    data = response.data;
                    // Do a custom callback for binding.expression
                }, response => {
                    // error callback
                });
            }
        );
    },
});
```

And im using it in various components, in this form:

```
<form method="POST" action="api/groups" v-ajax="customFunction"></form>
```

I would like the addGroup method called for the component in which the group is with data passed as a parameter...

```
Vue.component('x',{
    methods: {
        customFunction: function(data) : { }
    }
});
```

In this way I would be able to turn any form into AJAX submit, with the possibility to process the data differently for each component. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your directive needs multiple values `a callback function` and `data` and may add up in future. Assign your directive to object literal.

```
<form method="POST" action="api/groups" v-ajax="{successCb: customSuccessFunction, errorCb: customErrFunction, data: data}">
</form>
```

In your directive you can access them as below

```
Vue.directive('ajax', function (el, binding) {
  console.log(binding.value.successCb.color) // => customSuccessFunction
  console.log(binding.value.errorCb.text)  // => customErrFunction
  console.log(binding.value.data) // => data object
})
```